# unhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

(node:7152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null
at exports.login (C:\Users\niko\Desktop\opaa\controllers\controller.js:39:56)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:7152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

```
const User = require('../model/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.renderHomePage = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index') 
};

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const emailExist = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    //if (emailExist) return res.send('Email Exist')
 
    res.render('register')

    const hash = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.pass, hash);

    const user = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        password: hashPassword
        })
    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
    }catch(err){
        
    }
};

exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email1 });
    //if (!user) return res.send("Invalid Email");
    
    email1 = req.body.email1;
    pass1 = req.body.pass1;
    
    res.render('login')

    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(pass1, user.password);

    res.send("logged in");
    

    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.TOKEN);
    res.header('auth-token', token).send();

};
```

Comment: (node:11672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either 
by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: put a try catch block in the login middleware with the next call : try{ .... } catch(error) { next(error) }

Comment: It cannot find the user by email in your login function on `reg.body.email1`. Body does not contain `email1`?  The user does not exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to use the bodyParser package in order your body become readable.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser